# aws cognito google social login using react without hosted ui and without amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, google-signin

i am trying to integrate google social login to our react application without using hosted UI.
kindly help if some body having code using aws cognito+google social login+react
Thanks in advance

kindly share code link.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can direct target the Amazon Cognito [Authorize endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) and set `identity_provider=Google` on the URL.

> If you include an identity_provider or idp_identifier parameter in the URL, it silently redirects your user to the sign-in page for that identity provider (IdP).

The OAuth 2.0 REST API endpoints are fully documented under [User pool OIDC and hosted UI API endpoints reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-userpools-server-contract-reference.html)

Comment: Can you please provide me with some details documents? Because it's hard to understand the flow, which API needs to call 1, then 2, 3. In the document, they provide all API but the flow is correct. There is a blog link or any guide?